# DXGI AcquireNextFrame receives the next frame only after 20ms (50fps), is it possible to speed up to 10ms?

Tags: c++, video, directx, record, dxgi

Good afternoon.

I'm writing a program that would record video from the desktop at 100 fps, but I ran into a problem, AcquireNextFrame receives the next image from the desktop only after 20 ms, because of this, the maximum fps that I can get will be 50, you can do something with this?

Thanks.

Comment: AcquireNextFrame will receive nothing if nothing changes on the captured output. It's not like a "CaptureScreen" command. Timouts are expected and must taken into account. That's why you can't really design a workflow (like capture => convert => render or encode) on just one unique thread. Microsoft official "DXGIDesktopDuplication" sample is designed with multiple threads for that reason: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/DXGIDesktopDuplication But it can perfectly capture at 100fps if the screen changes at that speed (and you have good drivers, GPU).

Comment: Good afternoon, could you please write your comment as a solution? I will mark it as a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IDXGIOutputDuplication::AcquireNextFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgioutputduplication-acquirenextframe) will receive nothing if nothing changes on the captured output.

It's not like a "*PleaseCaptureScreenNow*" command.

Timouts are expected and must taken into account. That's why you can't really design a workflow for example like *capture => convert => copy/encode* on just one unique thread.

Microsoft official [DXGIDesktopDuplication](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/DXGIDesktopDuplication) sample is designed with multiple threads for that reason.

This method can perfectly capture at 100fps or more if the screen changes at that speed (and you have good GPU, drivers, etc.).

Comment: why can not use unique thread? I do not unserstand

Comment: @user666 - you can but it's often not ideal. In a capture workflow where you want to send frames to anyther system (another screen, a file, the network, an encoder, etc.), you'll want to capture what's possible to capture at the rate provided by DXGI (when what's output to the screen changes) handling timeouts gracefully, and then provide the feed to the other system at another speed. It depends on your other system but for example if it's a video feed, you want to continue sending frames (at least markers) even when nothing changes on DXGI side

Comment: If I want to send frames to network. if there is no change to send then othere size of the network will work and do not change too. keep last frame.

by the way if I send to network should I encode the frame to h264 by IMFTransfomr? thank you

Comment: @user666 - Yes, you could typically use MF and its H264 encoder for that.

Comment: but how to encode the texture? I need to map it and read the bytes and create IMFMediaBuffer?

Comment: @user666 - you should ask another question

Comment: sorry but I can not post new questions now.